# no python 3.10 modules availables

Tags: python, python-3.x, windows, module

i make everyday python 3.10 scripts (so all my modules are installed), but today all my scripts don't work. it gives me same error for each module ('ModuleNotFoundError: No module named x')

what could be happened? thx

p.s. windows 10

Comment: could it be a path issue?

Answer (score 0):

solved. uninstall python and reinstall it, with all modules.